# Delete a record from SQLite database WHERE datetime contains date from variable

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, datetime, date-arithmetic, strftime

I want to DELETE every record with a datetime (e.g. 2022-11-10T??????????) using a date (e.g. 2022-11-10) from a variable. For example:

```
last_Date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

And use SQL like this:

```
cursor.execute("""
DELETE FROM alpaca_stock_prices_4H WHERE datetime = (?)
""", (last_Date))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the variable `last_Date` is a formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` date string but the column `datetime` in the table contains timestamps in the format `YYYY-MM-DDT??????????` so you can't compare them with the `=` operator.

Use SQLite's `strftime()` or `date()` function to format the `datetime`s also to `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
cursor.execute("""
DELETE FROM alpaca_stock_prices_4H WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime) = ?
""", (last_Date,))
```

or:

```
cursor.execute("""
DELETE FROM alpaca_stock_prices_4H WHERE date(datetime) = ?
""", (last_Date,))
```

If what you actually want is delete all yesterday's rows you can do it without passing a parameter, by using only SQL code:

```
cursor.execute("""
DELETE FROM alpaca_stock_prices_4H WHERE date(datetime) = date('now', '-1 day'))
""")
```